# Unable to capture new lines from a console and save them into a text file

Tags: python, linux, console, newline

The following source code is supposed to capture output from the console and save that into a text file.

```
import sys
import subprocess
sys.stdout = open("my_app.txt", "w")
print(subprocess.check_output(
        ['./my_app', 
        '-length=7', 
        '-all', 
        '-file_names=tmpl.txt']        
        ), 
      '\n'
    )
sys.stdout.close()
```

The above source code is expected to output the following output:

```
1a62  A    4 THR H CCHHHHH 7.042 5.781 5.399 5.373 5.423  -9.118     
1a62  A    5 GLU H CHHHHHC 5.781 5.399 5.373 5.423 5.247   5.488   
1a62  A    6 LEU H HHHHHCC 5.399 5.373 5.423 5.247 5.485   5.166
```

However, I am getting the following output:

```
1a62  A    4 THR H CCHHHHH 7.042 5.781 5.399 5.373 5.423  -9.118\n1a62  A    5 GLU H CHHHHHC 5.781 5.399 5.373 5.423 5.247   5.488\n1a62  A    6 LEU H HHHHHCC 5.399 5.373 5.423 5.247 5.485   5.166
```

In other words, the new lines on `stdout` are not being recognized/captured/parsed properly.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> For `stdin`, line ending characters `'\n'` in the input will be converted to the default line separator `os.linesep`. For `stdout` and `stderr`, all line endings in the output will be converted to '\n'. For more information see the documentation of the [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) class when the newline argument to its constructor is `None`.

Since that you should add `text=True` parameter if you are using Python 3.7+, `universal_newlines=True` else. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

```py
print(subprocess.check_output([
    './my_app',
    '-length=7',
    '-all',
    '-file_names=tmpl.txt'
], text=True),
    '\n'
)
```